# PythonスクレイピングでGoogle検索画面情報取得

Tags: python3, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

https://torahack.com/python-scraping-for-seo/
このサイトにあるように、

①検索結果上位サイトのURLを取得
②title,description等を抜き出す。
③CSVで出力、ダウンロード

ということをやりたいのですが、うまくいきません。
下記のGoogle colabファイルを作成実行したところ
csvファイルが生成されるのですが、中身は空でした。

どなたか、うまくいく方法をご存じの方はおられないでしょうか。

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mW3E74mPd_cIAtkbEn7sudOT4n1s3aT4

コードは下記です。

```
import requests
import bs4
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd
from google.colab import files
import re

# 検索したいキーワードを入力する
listKeyword = ['犬', '猫']

#　取得したい件数に合わせて数値を変更する
searchNum = str(2)

response = requests.get('https://www.google.co.jp/search?num='+searchNum+'&q=' + '　'.join(listKeyword))
response.raise_for_status()

# 取得したHTMLをパースする
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

file_prefix = ""
for word in listKeyword:
  if (file_prefix == ""):
    file_prefix += str(word)
  else:
    file_prefix += "-" + str(word)

fileName = file_prefix+'_Top'+searchNum+'.csv'

# csvファイルのヘッダーを設定する
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['URL','Title','Description','metakey'])

sleepCounter = 0

# 検索結果上位サイトのURLを取得する
for a in soup.select('div#search h3.r a'):
  sleepCounter += 1
  url = re.sub(r'/url\?q=|&sa.*', '',a.get('href'))

  try:
    # 取得したURLを読み込む
    search = requests.get(url)
    searchSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(search.content, "html.parser")

    # タイトルの取得
    titleList = []
    for a in searchSoup.select('title'):
      titleList.append(a.text)     
    title=''

    for index,item in enumerate(titleList):
      if index==0:
        title = item
      else:
        title = title + ', ' +item

    # ディスクリプションの取得
    descriptionList = []
    for a in searchSoup.select('meta[name="description"]'):
      descriptionList.append(a.get('content'))
    description='No data'

    for index,item in enumerate(descriptionList):
      if index==0:
        description = item
      else:
        description = description + ', ' +item

    # キーワードの取得
    keywordList = []
    for a in searchSoup.select('meta[name="keywords"]'):
      keywordList.append(a.get('content'))     
    keywords = 'No data'

    for index,item in enumerate(keywordList):
      if index==0:
        keywords = item
      else:
        keywords = keyword + ', ' +item

  except: #例外処理：サイトを読み込めなかったときにする処理
    print('Failed to read web site.')

  # 取得したURL、タイトル、ディスクリプション、キーワードを追加する
  outputRow = [url,title,description,keywords]
  s = pd.Series(outputRow, index=['URL','Title','Description','metakey']) 
  df = df.append(s, ignore_index=True)

  # 10件以上検索する場合、秒間リクエスト数の制限を守るため、10件ごとに10秒の待機時間を設ける
  if sleepCounter > 10:
    sleep(10)
    sleepCounter = 0

# csvに出力する
df.to_csv(fileName, index=False)

# csvをダウンロードする
files.download(fileName)
```

Comment: 解決マークはありませんが、この記事 [How to scrape a google search results page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51286702/9014308) によると、「問題は、それが低レベルのhttpスクレイピングを検出するので、GoogleがそのSERPページの異なるHTMLバージョンを提供することです。」ということらしいです。「検出されないようにするには、Chromeとseleniumのような自動ブラウザを使用することをお勧めします。」か、紹介されている [GoogleScraper](https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper) を試してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: 直接の回答ではありませんが、Google の自然検索結果を取得したいのであればGoogle の Webのスクレイピングではなく Google Custom Search API を使う方が正規かと思います。 (参考 : https://qiita.com/zak_y/items/42ca0f1ea14f7046108c )

Answer (score 1):

requestsから戻ってきたcontentがfor文で使っているselectにヒットしていないようです。
Googleのhtmlの様式が変わったことが原因かと思いますが、単純に下記の構文ならばそれっぽいURLを取得できたのでこれを改修して目的を達成できるかもしれません。
ただしまた様式が変わるとコードが使い物にならなくなりますので、コメントに寄せられた方法を使うことをお勧めします。

```
import requests
import bs4
import re

# 検索したいキーワードを入力する
listKeyword = ['犬', '猫']

#　取得したい件数に合わせて数値を変更する
searchNum = str(2)

response = requests.get('https://www.google.co.jp/search?num='+searchNum+'&q=' + '　'.join(listKeyword))
response.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

# 検索結果上位サイトのURLを取得する(取得できない)
for a in soup.select('div#search h3.r a'):
    print('aがあればここを通ります')

# 検索結果の'/url'から始まるURLを取得する
for link in [a.get('href') for a in soup.select('a') if a.get('href').startswith('/url')]:
    url = re.sub(r'/url\?q=|&sa.*', '', link)
    print(url)
```