# googleニュースのスクレイピングのやり方

Tags: python

こんばんは、最近Pythonを勉強しはじめた学生です。pythonを用いてGoogleニュースのスクレイピングをしようとしているのですが、思う通りに動かないので、プロフェッショナルの皆様からお力を貸していただきたいです。
今現在、「独学プログラマーの本」を読みながら勉強しているのですが、この本に書いてある通り、

```
>>>import urllib.request
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site
    def scrape(self):
        r = urllib.request.urlopen(self.site)
        html = r.read()
        parser = "html.parser"
        sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
        for tag in sp.find_all("a"):
            url = tag.get("href")
            if url is None:
                continue
            if "html" in url:
                print("\n" + url)


>>> news = "https://news.google.com/"
>>> Scraper(news).scrape()
```

とコードを書いたのですが、何も表示されません(本来だとgoogleニュースのヘッドライン記事のURLが出てくるようです)。ちなみに、エラーも表示されません。どうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: 関連質問: [Google検索結果のスクレイピングができない。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60393) / スクレイピングはGoogleの規約によって禁止されているようですのでご注意を。 ["Google の利用規約では、どのような種類かに関わらず、自動化されたクエリを Google から明示的な許可を事前に得ずに Google のシステムに送信することは禁止されています。"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66357)

Comment: 掲示されているソースコードに `if "html" in url:`  という部分がありますが、取得している `a` タグの `href` には `html` という文字列が含まれていません。そのため、何も出力されません。

Comment: [Webスクレイピングコードが動作しません。](https://teratail.com/questions/150749)

Comment: [Webscraping Code Outputted Nothing to Shell · Issue #21 · calthoff/self_taught](https://github.com/calthoff/self_taught/issues/21)